# Use Azure AD access token to Authenticate to Azure DevOps with Flask

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

I registered an app in my Azure Active Directory, [which has permissions to Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLcvl.png)

I downloaded the Python Flask app, through the Azure quickstart, which can also be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp and it worked great.
However, I couldn't understand how to use the access token to also authenticate to Azure DevOps and use its REST API.

I have found this link here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) which says to register an app on Azure DevOps but it requires an HTTPS website for the callback which I currently don't have in the development phase.
I also cannot use Azure DevOps Personal Access Token since the purpose of this program is for different users to perform actions on their behalf and not to use a single account.

Is it possible to use the token acquired from Azure Active Directory and use it on Azure DevOps? and how can this be done using Flask?

Edit:
I was able to get the token using Postman, however -
[I'm constantly getting a 203 error as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFSnx.png)

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I have a package that works with Azure AD. You can give it a try https://github.com/evansmwendwa/python-socialite